# Disable Media Button receiver (in other app), or send intent to a specific app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I need to either disable `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` receiver for some time (less than 1 second, actually), or send `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` to specific app.
Is it possible, if I have class names of receivers?

Comment: By "Media Button intent", do you mean [`ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON)?

Answer (score 0):

`ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` is not sent as an ordered broadcast. You have no means of preventing other applications from responding to that broadcast, when the broadcast is sent by the system in response to an actual media button press, etc. Everyone who is registered for it gets it, in some indeterminate order.

If *you* are broadcasting `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON`, you are welcome to create an explicit `Intent`, identifying a particular `BroadcastReceiver`, that happens to also have the `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` action, and send that.

Answer (score 0):

After an hour of googling the web, I found the solution. I am using `intent.setPackage(String packageName)` now. Just for other people.